# How to read the REST request in soapui using java/groovy

Tags: java, rest, groovy, soapui

For Example:

[REST Request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRKXI.png)

I want to read these REST matrix request using Java or groovy.

What could be the possible solution?

Comment: Please keep in mind that It's not the json request. It's in tabular form. and i want to read all of them using java or groovy code. Just like we read the request/response in soap using xmlholder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check where they are the properties. 
You review the attachment.

[Show properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Qaf5.jpg)

You follow this steps:

- 1. Create a testSuite with the testcase.
- 2. Add the activity Groovy script and you add this code.

---

```
 //Print all properties
log.info  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TESTSTEP').getPropertyList().name;
log.info  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TESTSTEP').getPropertyList().value;
//Get value propertie
def value_property = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TESTSTEP').getPropertyValue('NAME_PROPERTY');
//Print Get value propertie
log.info  value_property 
//Set value Property
testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName('NAME_TESTSTEP').setPropertyValue('NAME_PROPERTY','VALUE');
```

- 3. You need to update the values (*NAME_TESTSTEP ,NAME_PROPERTY ,VALUE*)
- 4. Run the grrovy script.

Comment: Thank you, it really helped.

Comment: @AshutoshAnshu, then you should consider accepting it as answer.